# NPM Notice when installing any npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I keep receiving the following notice(shown below) whenever I install an npm package. Not sure what I am doing wrong, tried reinstalling node.js as well.

"npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/ "

I read another post indicating that "npm set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/" and "npm install -g [https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz"](https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz%22) works but I am not sure where and how and which directory I should perform this action. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

The `-g` flag means that the NPM package will be installed globally. Type the two commands mentioned above at the command prompt and run them. The first will set the registry to use HTTPS and the second command will verify that the HTTPS (TLS 1.2) connection is working.

After entering the second command, you should see something like:
"Hello! The tls-test package was successfully downloaded and installed. Congratulations! Your package manager appears to support TLS 1.2."